# Why can't I override text-decoration for visited links?

Tags: css

Please could someone explain why this doesn't seem to work? It's pretty straight-forward. I want links on the page to default to blue without an underline, and one they're clicked, I want it to change to purple with a line-through. However, my code doesn't work.

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: blue;
}

a:visited {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: purple;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">Google (click me)</a> &lt;-- Once clicked, it should have a line through it<br>
<!-- Had to add an onclick event as clicking the link doesn't seem to work without it -->
<a href="http://some-random-non-existant-site.com/">Non-existant Site</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thefuzzy0ne/hfqdsr4z/

I've tried varying combinations of `text-decoration-line` and `text-decoration-style` and still nothing seems to work. I normally don't have much trouble with CSS, but this is driving me nuts.

Comment: [For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit which styles you can apply using this pseudo-class, and how they can be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're limited to the attributes of the visited pseudo-class selector you can change for privacy reasons, so you can only style the following:

```
color
background-color
border-color
border-bottom-color
border-left-color
border-right-color
border-top-color
column-rule-color
outline-color
```